# Open Cover $(0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Find and proof an open cover of $(0, 1)$ that has no finite subcover.

I need to find an example and also proof the example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(0,1)=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n})$ is an open cover but has no finite subcover

Comment: To modify this interval to (1,2), would you just add 1 to each of those terms? e.g. (1+$1 \over n$, 2 - $1 \over n$)?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the example above, $\cup_{n \ge 2} (0,1-\frac{1}{n})$ is a open cover for $(0,1)$ with no (finite) sub-cover.